# How to compile a NodeJS program correctly so that it can be called from the console like nodemon?

Tags: javascript, node.js, compilation, console, exe

I recently developed a [tool](https://github.com/alexKudryavtsev-web/npm-defect) that I would like to share with the community. It consists of one JS file.

According to my logic, it should work like this:

1. `npm i -g npm-defect`
2. `npm-defect ...`

I already uploaded the library to NPM, but I don’t know how to make it so that it can be called from the console.

Tell me how to compile the program correctly so that it can be run that way.

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `npx`,  `npx npm-defect` , check this link to see how it works [npx doc](https://nodejs.dev/learn/the-npx-nodejs-package-runner) , or if you would like to package it as an executable use a node.js packager like  [vercel pkg](https://github.com/vercel/pkg)